# When cooking meats such as pork chops in a toaster oven, is it better to use butter or some type of oil to coat the pan?

Tags: meat, oil, oven, butter, non-stick

I often use a toaster oven where I line the tray with aluminum foil and coat it in something so the food doesn't stick. Is a difference between using butter or olive oil or some other type of oil to prevent the meat from sticking and make it taste rich?

Answer (score 2):

Also depends on how hot your toaster oven gets. Butter burns at 350 F, most oils dont burn until at least 400 F.

Heres a list of temperatures at which different oils burn http://whatscookingamerica.net/Information/CookingOilTypes.htm

Usually Ill start with oil and add some butter towards the end for flavor if Im cooking on a high heat.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of oil or butter is entirely based on your preference for flavor, and how how want the pork chops to come out.

With some seasonings like Southwestern seasonings, you might choose an oil.  With others, for example if you were planning a french sauce with shallots and mustard, you might go with the butter.

Butter will have a very slightly greater tendency to stick, but it is probably not worth worrying about.

This has nothing to do with the toaster oven, by the way.